# How to log in over network with CMD via UNC path?

Tags: networking, cmd, file-transfer

I want to be able to connect to a remote machine through its UNC path in either windows CMD or powershell; I have tried `C:\pushd \\MyServer\"User Folders"\localUser\TestFolder` but when this executes, I get "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password"

is "pushd" even the right command to use here? I have files that I want to exchange between the two machines on the same network, can there be permission bits I'm overlooking here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `pushd` is not the right command. For connecting to a remote share you need the command `net use`:

```
net use X: \\SERVER\SHARE /user:DOMAIN\USER
```

If you're using the same account on both hosts (both a domain account as well as identical local accounts will work) you can omit the `/user:DOMAIN\USER` part.

Normally you'd connect only to the share, but you can also connect directly to some folder below the share:

```
net use X: \\SERVER\SHARE\some\subfolder
```

Comment: Yes, `pushd` _can_ be the right command. If executed against a share it will automatically allocate a free drive letter and assign it to the share, than changing into that directory / drive.

Comment: Not if you need to provide credentials.

Answer (score 1):

`pushd` should work for you, given that you have the required permissions to access the share as the current user.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490978.aspx):

> If you specify a network path, the pushd command temporarily assigns
>   the first unused drive letter (starting with Z:) to the specified
>   network resource. The command then changes the current drive and
>   directory to the specified directory on the newly assigned drive. If
>   you use the popd command with command extensions enabled, the popd
>   command removes the drive-letter assignation created by pushd.

Note that the Powershell `pushd` alias (really `Push-Location`) does not map a drive letter, but otherwise works the same, i.e. lets you use the respective share as current directory.

So, yes it looks like you have a permission problem. Try accessing the share using explorer (or `net use` as @Ansgar Wiechers suggests in his answer, or even a simple `dir \\share\...`) to cross check.